# kernel panic not syncing vfs unable to mount root fs on unknown block oo swapper not tainted

Tags: kernel

I updated my laptop (Ubuntu) to 11.10 and I don't know what went wrong that when I restarted the computer It would start and it would only tell me.

> kernel panic not syncing vfs unable to mount root fs on unknown block
>   oo swapper not tainted...

I am a new user and I have no idea what to do. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9):

You are missing the initramfs for that kernel. Choose another kernel from the grub menu, or run update-initramfs -u -k version to generate the initrd for version then update-grub.

Boot to a LiveCD, select Try Ubuntu and then open a a terminal. Run the following:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

This will show us what partitions are available. You need to look for your main Ubuntu partition. On most fresh-installed systems this will be `sda1` but it really could be anything. Substitude `sda1` in the following with whatever you decide is right in the `fdisk` output.

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
sudo mount --bind /run /mnt/run
sudo chroot /mnt
```

And now you can run `update-initramfs` and `update-grub` with out errors and that should fix everything. Reboot without the CD in and you should land on your Ubuntu desktop.

---

Additionally, after the chroot:

```
cp -r /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pango /usr/lib/

update-initramfs -u -k 2.6.38-8-generic #(or your version)
update-grub2
```

(You can find a list if installed kernels using: `dpkg --list | grep linux-image`)
And reboot your system

Comment: +1 this worked for me after crashed Virtual machine. I just mount , updated-initframfs and update-grub2. I checked last kernel version in /boot/grub/grub.init.

Comment: Awesome! This worked perfectly. I only had a Knoppix Live CD available, but it still worked great.

Comment: I cannot even get to the command line in recovery mode in order to execute these commands.  What do I do?

Comment: This worked for me. Booted using other kernel, and ran the above commands

Answer (score 0):

1. Get/burn an installation CD with a linux system.
2. Booted from this CD (may need to press F12 (or other key) to choose
   boot option).
3. Mount the old file system on, I use:

   Code:

   ```
   mount -t ext4 /dev/sda1 /mnt
   ```
4. In ROOT account, went to my boot volume (at /mnt/boot/grub) and
   edited "grub.conf" so that (A) I would see the menu and (B) it would
   give me a few seconds to choose and option:

   Code:

   ```
   timeout=10
   #hiddenmenu
   ```
5. Rebooted (from the hard disk this time).
6. Chose the second kernel (not the most recent broken one).
7. It worked!
8. So, then I went back to grub (now at "/etc/grub.conf", which is
   soft linked to "/boot/grub/grub.conf") and edited it to comment out
   (or remove) the lines relating to the broken kernel:

   Code:

   ```
   # title Fedora (2.6.40-4.fc15.i686)
   #        root (hd0,0)
   #        kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.40-4. ......
   ```

I noticed this stanza does not have "initrd ..." line. Maybe that's why it
couldn't boot.