# How to fix kernel panic with read/write error?

Tags: installation, boot, partitioning

Whenever I start my computer it first says "error attempt to read or write out of partition".

Then on another screen it says:

```
[       1.378476] Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unsble to mount root fs on unknown block (0,0).
```

Specs that I know of:

A midrange asus laptop with an amd a6 vision processor, radeon graphics hd 6520g graphics card. This is pretty urgent because i'm about to start school in about a week so assistance would be very nice.

I installed ubuntu from a dvd and at first it worked just fine until I had to restart it for some changes to take place then this happened. I tried doing a memory test but then after 13 hours it said there was no errors so I stopped it.

Comment: Seen this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/116635/kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block-oo-swapper

Comment: It says that it can't find command 'sudo'

Comment: Get a Live CD and boot your laptop with it, then proceed with Oli's Link.

Comment: It seems that your disk drive is hosed.  Boot the livecd, download and run this script, and edit the results into your question: http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/