# Kernel panic on boot up with 13.10 live-USB

Tags: 13.10, kernel, system-installation

I am a new user for Ubuntu. I downloaded 13.10 yesterday and made a bootable USB with universal USB installer on my Lenovo IdeaPad Z580 laptop which is now using UEFI; everything appeared OK.

When I booted from the LiveUSB I got the choices of trying or installing Ubuntu but both of them keep giving me these error:

```
[ 1.929082] kernel panic-not syncing vfs unable to mount root fs on
unknown-block (0.0)
```

Please tell me what is going wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu! Can you add the name of the computer you're using to the question?

Comment: @Aaron - depends what you mean by `name` - I think you mean the computer's make and model?

Comment: *Lenovo* _Z580_

Comment: @Aaron *yes I wrote it just now*

Comment: @wilf: Sorry, I should have been clearer :). That's what I meant.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [kernel panic not syncing vfs unable to mount root fs on unknown block oo swapper not tainted](http://askubuntu.com/q/116635)

Comment: Asus vivobook S200E. same thing. Tried to `dd if=ubuntu13.10.iso of=/dev/sdX bs=4M`... tried to `unetbootin` after creating a fat32 partition on the usb drive... all boot me to the UEFI boot, i can see grub(?) and then i get this message. removing `quiet splash` to `nosplash` (really idiotic to have quiet on the install boot) i can see a LZM error so it is probably a bad download/USB memory?

Comment: 1st step, check the hash: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes  then try another usb device/port.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the USB may not have created the filesystem properly, so I would reformat the USB Flash Drive (as FAT32, the most common format for bootable USB FlashDrives) then reinstall the LiveUSB with Universal USB Installer again.

When the PC reboots, disable the UEFI function in your BIOS. I believe the BIOS listing should be UEFI/Legacy Boot and changing that to Legacy Only will solve the other possible source of your problem.

It's also a general good idea to specify which version (e.g., Ubuntu with Unity, [Ubuntu GNOME](http://ubuntugnome.org), [Kubuntu](http://kubuntu.org), [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org) or [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net)) of Ubuntu you are trying to install.

Comment: *computer(Lenovo Z580) is using UEFI, version is 13.10, please tell me why FAT32 formatting?? Thanks.*

Comment: @MuhammadEmad Fat32 is a universally recognized filesystem, and most systems can read, even old ones, so you don't have to worry about your computer's ability to read it.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to install Ubuntu from a USB disk on a Windows 7 system led to a lot of errors. I found that, in addition to disabling Windows active security protection during the time I was using uNetBootin but also that my flash drive was too big (64gb).

For me the issue was that I was using exFAT which is a proprietary filesystem. Since it is not generally recognizable, that was the first error. In order to get around this, I ran: `FORMAT/FS:FAT32 E:` (E: being my USB drive).

After this, installing with UNetBootin went fine. But do not use exFAT to try to install from a USB drive, it's not supported.