# Live USB Kernel Panic error?

Tags: boot, usb, kernel, dell

I tried to make a 14.04 live USB with Universal USB Installer. I get to the screen where it says Try Ubuntu, Install Ubuntu, etc. but no matter what I select, it eventually ends in this error;

`end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(2,0)`

Does anyone know how to fix this? The computer that this is on is a Dell Inspiron 1545. I've seen a few cases around where you had to format the flash drive as FAT32, but I tried that and it still displayed the same message.

Sorry if this is a duplicate. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and eventually found the answer here:

[Kernel panic on boot up with 13.10 live-USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/399071/kernel-panic-on-boot-up-with-13-10-live-usb/399076#399076)

In my case, the format of the bootable flash drive was not a format that windows could understand.  I needed to format the flash drive as FAT32 and then use unetbootin to make it bootable again.

Comment: suggest links in comments, this is not an answer

Comment: I flagged as probable duplicate as well as posting the answer here.  I felt that the connection between the two questions wasn't so obvious, so I wanted to add a little more detail.  If it's possible to delete the answer, I will gladly move it to a comment.

Answer (score 1):

The most common reason for such cases is that the bootable USB disk is not readable - either because the hardware is failing, or because it was not written properly, or the image was corrupted during download.

- Retry in a different USB port
- Check the image integrity ( see [How can I check the integrity of a downloaded Ubuntu CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17764/how-can-i-check-the-integrity-of-a-downloaded-ubuntu-cd?noredirect=1&lq=1) )
- Redownload, possibly reformat the live USB disk to FAT32 ( see [Setup Error: end kernel panic - not syncing: vfs: unable to mount root fs on unknown block(2,0)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/592213/setup-error-end-kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unk?rq=1) ), write the live image again
- If problem persists (especially if the boot is suspiciously slow), try with a different USB drive.