# kernel panic-not syncing: VFS: unable to mount root fs on unknown block(0,2)

Tags: boot, kernel, mount

I'm so new to Linux and suddenly found the error message appear when i boot after i click install ubuntu

```
Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,2)
```

Comment: sorry Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,2) not (0,0)

Comment: I have got kernel panic when I was trying to install ubuntu from ntfs pendrive. Solution was fat, but I don't know it will be right in your issue.

Answer (score 7):

Same thing happened to me also, here's how to get it back:

First, try to boot in recovery mode:
Follow the instructions in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell).

If you manage to get to the root prompt where you can type commands, things are looking good. This should make your system bootable again:

```
update-initramfs -u  
update-grub2
```

---

If you cannot get a root prompt at all, then get a LiveCD (the cd / usb key you used to install ubuntu should work) and boot from it. Then you have a useable system from which you can access the broken one:
Follow dilip's instructions in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116635/kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block-oo-swapper)

Comment: To generate `initrd` for a particular kernel version (e.g. 3.13.0.46-generic): `update-initramfs -u -k 3.13.0.46-generic`

Comment: To list out all kernel versions in the system: `ls -al /usr/src`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the partition **/boot** has no space.

In the grub, select a previous kernel linux-image, if you have linux-image-22 try 21. after you enter,  go to **/boot** and remove the oldest kernel images.

**#apt-get remove linux-image-XXX**

reboot the system.
good lucky!

Comment: I don't think that's what's happening here.  The error clearly talks aboutr the `root fs `.  While `/boot` might indeed fill up, that usually only happens when you have it as a small partition (often in an LVM setup).  For most normal Linux uses, `/boot` is just part of `/`... So if `/boot` would be full, so would be `/` itself.